# MySQL import data from a csv file via LOAD DATA INFILE does not work

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I tried so hard to get this command work. Nothing is happening. Here is my issue:

I have a .csv file which I am uploading to my server where I want to run a script to import all of the data into a MySQL table. The csv looks like this:

```
id;herstellernr;hersteller;firmenname;url
123;ABC;Hersteller1;Firmenname1;http://www.test.com
234;DEF;Hersteller2;Firmenname2;http://www.test2.de
345;GHI;Hersteller3;Firmenname3;http://www.test3.net
```

... and so on.

After uploading the csv file, I first want to create a new table (temporary) where my data should be imported. Creating the table works without any problems; getting my Data imported from the csv file doesn't.

Here is my script (which comes after the upload script):

```
$temp = $pdo->prepare("

CREATE TABLE ".$name."
(
   id int(11),
   herstellernr varchar(3),
   hersteller varchar(150),
   firmenname varchar(255),
   url varchar(100),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

LOAD DATA INFILE '_csv/".$filename."' INTO TABLE ".$name."
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, herstellernr, hersteller, firmenname, url)

");

$temp->execute(array());
```

`CREATE TABLE` works but after that there is nothing happening with my `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Plus: I don't really know if it should be '\n' or '\r\n'. Anyway both cases didn't work.

I tried really hard and I am sure the syntax is just right. But I can't make it. Can you help? Thank you

Comment: You cannot use multiple queries with PDO. Break each statement into a separate query. You do not need to prepare the query since you're not actually using parameters. A straight query will work fine for each statement.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm not that fit with SQL and PDO. Can you show me a solution with my example?! Would be just _GREAT_ :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use multiple queries with PDO. You'll need to break them up into separate queries. Since you're not using bound parameters, you can skip the prepare, as well:

```
$pdo->query("CREATE TABLE ".$name."
(
   id int(11),
   herstellernr varchar(3),
   hersteller varchar(150),
   firmenname varchar(255),
   url varchar(100),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci");

$pdo->query("LOAD DATA INFILE '_csv/".$filename."' INTO TABLE ".$name."
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(id, herstellernr, hersteller, firmenname, url)");
```

Comment: Thank you. This is resulting in Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in /www/htdocs/.../:65 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /www/htdocs/.../_update_csv.php on line 65

Comment: Which is this line: $pdo->execute("CREATE TABLE ".$name."

Comment: Oops, I think that should have been query, not execute. Let me update that.

Comment: Now it is creating the table but the data import is still not working :/ 0 rows. Thank you anyway

Comment: Another thing to note is that `LOAD DATA INFILE` needs a full path, and mysql must be able to access that directory. You can use [PDO error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to check for errors after your query to see if it works.

Comment: No, a local path, so `/var/www/path/to/file`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html, specifically the part talking about the `LOCAL` keyword, for what it's expecting and what the restrictions are.

Comment: But I am not using local? :/ Therefor i uploaded my file to the server..

Comment: That's why I suggested reading that section. `LOCAL` means something different when it comes to `LOAD INFILE`. `The LOCAL keyword affects expected location of the file and error handling, as described later. LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld was started with the local_infile system variable disabled, LOCAL does not work.`

Comment: `In the non-LOCAL case, these rules mean that a file named as ./myfile.txt is read from the server's data directory, whereas the file named as myfile.txt is read from the database directory of the default database.`

Comment: Thank you.. Well I changed my path for load data infile to my root dir /www/bla/bla/bla/bla/_csv/ ... i get these messages: NON LOCAL: Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'%' (using password: YES), LOCAL:The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version